# Отследить одновременное нажатие правой и левой кнопки мыши

Tags: python

Друзья, перерыл много текста, но так и не нашел решения в python. Если кто знает или может подскажите как реализовать подобное?

Если нажата_правая_кнопка_мыши и левая_кнопка_мыши:
выполняем_код

Вот примерно такой условный оператор, и какой лучше модуль для этого юзать? Заранее благодарю

Comment: Там для 1 клавиши, а мне надо чтобы отслеживалось сразу две